# Validar rich:calendar com data anterior a outro rich:calendar

Tags: jsf

Eu tenho 2 campos de data, o segundo não pode ser anterior aprimeiro, mas não estou conseguindo validar.

Toda vez que entra na validação a `dataInicio` SEMPRE é `null`.

Pelo o que vi do ciclo de vida do `jsf`, ele faz as validações primeiros para depois popular.

e no meu caso que preciso que o primeiro campo esteja preenchido o que se faz?

```
<rich:calendar 
    id="idDataCadastro"
    locale="pt_BR"
    popup="true"
    value="#{dataInicio}"
    datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
    showInput="true"
    label="Data de início"
    showApplyButton=""
    cellWidth="24px"
    cellHeight="22px"
    style="width:200px"
    required="true" >                                                   
</rich:calendar>


<rich:calendar 
    id="idDataCadastro"
    locale="pt,BR"
    popup="true"
    value="#{dataFim}"
    datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
    showInput="true"
    label="Data fim"
    showApplyButton=""
    cellWidth="24px"
    cellHeight="22px"
    style="width:200px"
    required="true"
    validator="#{beanController.validateDataFim}" >     
</rich:calendar>



public void validateDataFim(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object valor) throws ValidatorException {
    if(valor != null){
        Date dataFim= (Date) valor;         
        if(dataInicio != null && dataFim.before(dataInicio)){
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                    "A data fim não pode ser anterior a data inicio.", 
                    "A data fim não pode ser anterior a data inicio."));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o problema!
Na verdade meu código está correto o problema era outro framework que estou usando (Jboss SEAM 2.2),

o que aconteceu:

```
<rich:calendar 
    ...
    value="#{dataInicio}"  // Essa referência é criada e populada pelo JBoss Seam
    ...

<rich:calendar 
    ...
    validator="#{beanController.validateDataFim}" // Essa validação é do JSF
                                                  // O JSF não consegue enxergar
                                                  // dataInicio criada pelo Seam
                                                  // por isso sempre vinha null
```

Solução!!

```
<rich:calendar 
    ...
    value="#{beanController.dataInicio}"  // Trocar a referência
    ...
```